# Find the number of ordered triplets $x,y,z$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> Find the number of ordered triplets $(x,y,z)$ of positive integers less than $13$ such that the product $x\cdot y\cdot z$ is divisible by $20$.

My work:

The possible values of $x\cdot y\cdot z$ are $20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160$. I began to make cases. I made cases for the product to be equal to $20$. I got $27$ cases.

Then for the product to be equal to $40$, I got $36$ cases.

I see that the number of cases are getting bigger. I don't know the best method of doing these types of questions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Can we do it by the inclusion-exclusion principle$?$ Like counting all the triplets whose product does not divide both $5$ and $4$.

Here, $x,y,z$ have to be different as if it's not the case then the possible number of triplets exceed $216$.

Comment: you need that $xyz=20k=2^2\cdot 5\cdot k$, which implies that the factors of $2,2$ and $5$ has to divide $x,y$ or $z$. This give us some cases, but it is much simpler and faster than your method. Also it works for other numbers different from $20$

Comment: @Marcos can you pls elaborate

Comment: Does x=10, y=12, z=12, xyz=1440 count as a case? Your possible value of xyz stopped at 160. Did I misunderstood the question?

Comment: I think your list of possible values of $xyz$ is incomplete. $10\times11\times12=1320$ is a multiple of $20$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson i haven't found all cases..you're right

Comment: @AbelWong you're absolutely correct...im dumb..but wait no two of them can be same...it says ordered triplets...this is in my opinion

Comment: I think ordered tripet just mean (1,2,10) <> (10,2,1). This terms do not restirct x<=y<=z. see [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254522/ordered-triplet-mean-in-order)

Comment: @AbelWong oh i see..then will the answer still be 216??

Comment: I counted 463 by computer.

Comment: @AbelWong but the answer given is 216

Comment: I doubt this answer(216). If the answer is 463, I can show you my steps.

Comment: @AbelWong - I agree with 463 by computation.  A Python one-liner: sum([x*y*z % 20 == 0 for x in range(1, 13) for y in range(1, 13) for z in range(1, 13)])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a generating function approach. We consider the set of integers $\{1,2,3,\ldots,12\}$ and mark the occurrence of prime factors $2$ and $5$ according to their multiplicity with $z$ resp. $w$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
1&\color{blue}{z}&1&\color{blue}{z^2}&\color{blue}{w}&\color{blue}{z}&1&\color{blue}{z^3}&1&\color{blue}{zw}&1&\color{blue}{z^2}\\
\end{array}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We obtain from (1) the generating function $A(z,w)$ as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{A(z,w)=5+\left(2z+2z^2+z^3\right)+(1+z)w}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Since we want to count
\begin{align*}
|\{(x,y,z)\,:\,1\leq x,y,z\leq 12, 20|xyz\}|
\end{align*}
we calculate $A(z,w)^3$ which corresponds to the sum of products $x\cdot y\cdot z$ with $1\leq x,y,z\leq 12$ and count all terms which contain $z^2w$. These are the terms which correspond to a multiple of $20$.

> Denoting with $[z^n]$ the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k\geq 2}}&\color{blue}{\sum_{l\geq 1}[z^k][w^l]A(z,w)^3}\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 2}\sum_{l\geq 1}[z^k][w^l]\left(5+\left(2z+2z^2+z^3\right)+(1+z)w\right)^3\tag{3.1}\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 2}[z^k]\left((1+z)^3+3\cdot 5(1+z)+3\cdot 5(1+z)^2\right.\\
> &\qquad\quad+3\left(2z+2z^2+z^3\right)^2(1+z)\\
> &\qquad\quad+3\left(2z+2z^2+z^3\right)\left(1+z\right)^2\\
> &\qquad\quad+\left.6\cdot 5\left(2z+2z^2+z^3\right)(1+z)\right)\tag{3.2}\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 2}[z^k]\left(\left(3z^2+z^3\right)+3\cdot 5\cdot 0+3\cdot 5z^2\right.\\
> &\qquad\quad+3(5)^2(2)\\
> &\qquad\quad+3\left(\left(2z^2+z^3\right)+2\left(2z^2+2z^3+z^4\right)+\left(2z^3+2z^4+z^5\right)\right)\\
> &\qquad\quad\left.+6\cdot 5\left(2z+2z^2+z^3\right)(1+z)\right)\tag{3.3}\\
> &=4+0+15+150+3\left(3+2\cdot 5+5\right)+6\cdot 5\left(3+5\right)\tag{3.4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=463}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with other answers.

*Comment:*

- In (3.1) we consider a trinomial expansion
  \begin{align*}
  (a+b+c)^3&=a^3+b^3+c^3+3\left(a^2b+a^2c+ab^2+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2\right)\\
  &\qquad+6abc
  \end{align*}
- In (3.2) we select all terms which contains a factor $w$, i.e. which contains a factor $c$ in the expansion from $(a+b+c)^3$.
- In (3.3) we simplify terms by skipping constant and linear terms in $z$ and by counting some of the terms which contain a factor $z^k$ with $k\geq 2$.
- In (3.4) we simplify further until we finally derive the result.

Comment: This solution is so elegant!!!

Comment: @AbelWong: Many thanks. :-)

Comment: @EveryonesaysFU: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would condition on the number of x, y, z that are multiples of 5.

Let $F =\{4, 8, 12\}$; $E = \{2, 4, 6, 8, 12\}$; $O = \{1, 3, 7, 9, 11\}$ and $A=
\{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12\}$.

Then we can have

(a) Only 1 a multiple of 5. So $<5EE>$ (notation means a 5 and two elements of E), $<5FO>$, $<10EE>$, $<10EO>$.

$|<5EE>| = |E|\times 3 + {|E| \choose 2} \times 6$ (the two evens are equal, with 3 permutations of each or the two evens are distinct, with 6 permutations of each) = 75.

Similarly $|<5FO>| = |F|\times |O| \times 6$ = 90; $|<10EE>|$ = 75 and $|<10EO>|$ = 150. A total of 390.

(b) Exactly two are multiples of 5. So $<55F>$, $<510E>$, $<1010A>$, with $|<55F>| $ = 9; $|<510E>|$ = 30 and $|<1010A>|$ = 30. A total of 69.

(c) All three are multiples of 5. So $<101010>$ (only one), $<51010>$ (3 permutations). A total of 4.

Altogether 463.